Shelo Asani Isha for an intersex who becomes a man
According to the first comment to this answer there’s responsa from the Tzitz Eliezer where he says that a Jew born with both man and woman characteristics can choose their gender (not transgender, but  an indeterminate status becoming determinate), if so does such a Jew recite Shelo Asani Isha if choosing to be a man? Or they do not, even if they become a man according to Halacha since they were born androgynous do they not thank Hashem for not creating them a woman since they could have been one?

This is an enormously complex subject. The source sheet prepared by Rabbi Anthony Manning which can be found here https://rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Transgender-and-Gender-Reassignment.pdf is a very useful resource. Rabbi Manning addresses aspects of the teshuva of the Tzitz Eliezer (Rav Eliezer Waldenburg) on page 7

The last perek of Mishna Bikkurim addresses some of these issues. https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bikkurim.4?lang=bi

See the comments to that answer.
